# General rule: negative or positive values for error code in C/C++

Tags: c++, c

I have my own return type and functions defined like this:

```
typedef enum xx_return_t {
   success = 0,
   general_error = -1,
   specific_error = -2,
   [...]
} xx_return_type;

xx_return_type generalFunction(void) {
   if(there_was_an_error)
      return general_error;
}
```

However I'm a bit uncertain on the error type values here;
**what is standard/best practice for values of error returns in C/C++ - *negative or positive*?**

*Update:*
Thank you for your answers!
I was looking for info on both C and C++, but I also realize this raises good questions on general structure and methods specific to each language (exceptions, error codes, object returns, etc).

Comment: Are you asking about C or C++?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is really two totally different questions (C and C++ versions) disguised as one.

In C++ the answer is simple: Use return values for...returned data values and use exceptions for error/exception cases. Don't use return values for error checking in pure C++ (a C library API to C++ is a different story).

In C you don't have that option, so I would suggest using 0 for success and negative numbers for error codes. This leaves the flexibility, if desired, to use positive numbers for additional success information (for example `read` calls)

Comment: Regarding exceptions in C++, I would note that it does not mean that suddenly all methods should `throw`. For example: `T const* MyMap::find(std::string const& name);` is a method that need not throw when the name was not found; it can just return a null pointer.

Comment: I agree with Matthieu. Exceptions should be thrown only in case of exceptional events, not ordinary negative results of a search, etc. Throwing exception is much slower that returning value from function and even if it is not thrown the try{}catch() block itself and inclusion of all exception handling machinery makes the program slower.

Answer (score 4):

C++:

1. It's a matter of choice, I've seen both.
2. Use exceptions!

Comment: "2." works especially well for this `c` tag ;-)

Comment: (Wish there was a `+0.5` option ;-))

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker: It's always a problem with the C/C++ questions. Either it's C or it's C++...

Comment: @MatthieuM., I'd say *often*, not *always*. The question here is not whether it's c or c++, but rather whether it's "c and c++" or "c or c++" ;-)

Comment: @MatthieuM. Just like Stroustrup said: "I dont know of any language called C/C++" :)

Comment: Well there's always SEH for exceptions in C *ducks*

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker & MatthieuM s***w the C/C++ tag. Didn't even notice it.

Comment: You can put `C++` after `1.` :)

Answer (score 3):

There are several conventions to choose from:

- microsoft uses 0=FALSE=error for most of its high level api's. and let the user lookup the specific error with a global function `GetLastError()`
- microsoft uses 0=ok for lower level apis, like registry, audio, or telephony. these all return a type similar to `HRESULT`, containing the specific error code.
- posix functions returning a status usually return -1 for error, and let the user lookup the error via a global variable `errno`
- functions returning a pointer usually return NULL for error
- c++ STL functions return 'end' for status like 'not found'. errors like 'out-of-memory' are signalled using an exception.

In general, it is more important that you use your convention consistently, than which convention you use.

Btw, some examples of how not to do this can be found in microsoft's header files:

```
#define S_OK       ((HRESULT)0x00000000L)
#define S_FALSE    ((HRESULT)0x00000001L)
```

Also beware of two different error values for `HANDLE`'s in windows: either 0 or `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE`

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about C...

... but in C++ the idea is not to use error codes, in general.

I do not mean that you should use exceptions, but an error code is not really too informative (lacks context, what is the worth of `FILE_NOT_FOUND` when the file name is unknown ?).

In the instances that I did not use exceptions, I tended to prefer full blown error objects. An example could be:

```
boost::variant<File, Error> open(std::string const& filename, FileMode mode);
```

where you will get either a file or an error, depending on what's happening.

Answer (score 1):

Better to use 0 (zero) and non-zero so they can also be considered boolean. Typically false is 0, and true is anything else.

Comment: That's what he's doing & non-zero can be negative and positive...

Comment: @LuchianGrigore Actually, he's doing the opposite. As you mentioned, both are common, but its nice to be able to also use true/false.

Comment: What do you call the opposite? "using 0 and non-zero" as opposed to "using non-zero and 0"?

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker I meant he's using 0 as success, whereas Im suggesting 0 is false which is opposite of success.

Comment: @Brady, false is not opposite of success, false is the opposite of true. But now I see what you mean. Did you know that 99% of standard c-library calls and syscalls return 0 for success and error code otherwise and are very convenient as booleans?

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker, yes I knew that about the return 0 for success in C, but I think this answer would be better for both C and C++.

Comment: I disagree. Normally, there's one way to succeed and many reasons for failure. You're still entitled for your opinion, of course, but I'm still thinking for which answer to vote and it's not yours (sorry;)).

Comment: I agree. With Michael, that is. The reason for the 0=success return status is that oftentimes there are many different paths to failure. When a failure occurs, knowing which which one of the myriad problems did occur sometimes aids with recovery. No failure? Just move along and do the next thing that needs to be done.

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker I see your point of view. There should be only one success (true) and many failures, all of which are considered false, and Ive suggested the opposite :)

Comment: Yup. You suggest the world full of success and but one way to fail :) (as for treating it as a boolean, it *would* be a matter of `!` if in fact we weren't mostly interested in failure — as in `if(dostuff()) return non_zero_oh_no_while_doing_stuff_code;`).